# How to read mouse motion in bevy?

Tags: rust, game-development, bevy

I want to create a first person camera.
I already researched the source code of several other implementations like

https://github.com/mcpar-land/bevy_fly_camera

https://github.com/sburris0/bevy_flycam

But when implementing it by my own(mostly copy paste tbh) it fails to compile, when using the latest bevy version on git.

Compile output:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut (usize, PhantomData<MouseMotion>)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/player_input.rs:151:13
    |
151 |     mut state: ResMut<State>,
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*mut (usize, PhantomData<MouseMotion>)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    | 
   ::: /home/luca/.cargo/git/checkouts/bevy-f7ffde730c324c74/89a41bc/crates/bevy_ecs/src/resource/resource_query.rs:66:26
    |
66  | pub struct ResMut<'a, T: Resource> {
    |                          -------- required by this bound in `bevy::prelude::ResMut`
    |
    = help: within `player_input::State<'_>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut (usize, PhantomData<MouseMotion>)`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Local<'_, (usize, PhantomData<MouseMotion>)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `bevy::prelude::EventReader<'_, MouseMotion>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `player_input::State<'_>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Resource` for `player_input::State<'_>`
```

Here is the code:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct State<'a> {
    mouse_motion_event_reader: EventReader<'a, MouseMotion>,
}

fn mouse_motion_system(
    time: Res<Time>,

    mut state: ResMut<State>, //<-- IMPORTANT LINE (Line 151)

    mouse_motion_events: Res<Events<MouseMotion>>,
    mut query: Query<(&mut FlyCamera, &mut Transform)>,
) {
    //...
}
```

It only throws this error on the latest version of bevy and not on version 0.4.0.

Did I do something wrong or should I open an issue on github because it's the engine's fault?

What do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have `EventReader` in `State` here at all. Maybe you wanted to keep track of the last cursor position inside the state?

Since the event API was simplified for Bevy 0.5 you only need the `EventReader` as system parameter; `mouse_motion_events: Res<Events<MouseMotion>>,` is now obsolete and can be replaced with `mut mouse_motion_events: EventReader<MouseMotion>`.